# expresso store and omnipay

Tags: expresso-store

I am hoping to use store with omnipay, as it has tokenized payments.  I am prepared to code the plugin for my particular payment gateway, but is exp-resso planning to use omnipay in future releases?

If so, when?

Comment: For questions like this it is best to reach out to the developers directly. If you shoot an email to support@exp-resso.com they can take care of you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request for a product, not a request for help

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite as simple as that. Omnipay might support token payments, but Store itself doesn't. Even if you wrote your gateway for Omnipay, that wouldn't give you the ability to easily save credit cards and charge them with Store, there would still be a lot of database logic etc missing. So it depends entirely on what you are trying to do.

As Justin mentioned, it's probably easier to contact support@exp-resso.com with questions like this so we can discuss what you are trying to do and the best way to approach it.